# Custom Domain for Google Compute Engine Server

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Can I get the external IP of compute engine instance point to a custom domain name that I own ?

---

I've found a number of links of accomplishing it with App Engine and therefore, presently I'm thinking of calling the Compute Engine from App Engine. Kindly share your thoughts about this solution as well

Comment: How did you end up doing it? I am currently trying to [deploy my GWT application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530367/deploying-a-gwt-application-to-google-compute-engine-what-is-happening-here) to GCE but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an extenal static IP adress and use it in your own domain DNS setup.
Docs: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#externaladdresses

Docs: *You can assign an optional externally visible IP address to specific instances. Outside callers can address a specific instance by external IP if the network firewalls allow it. Only instances with an external address can send and receive traffic from outside the network.*